# undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to override reset password controller with devise but anyhow it is giving me this error. I can't understand what is the actual reason. I am sharing my code

**passwords_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

    skip_before_action :require_login!


    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
      @user = User.send_reset_password_instructions(params[:user])
      if successfully_sent?(@user)
        head :status => 200
      else
        render :status => 422, :json => { :errors => @user.errors.full_messages }
      end
    end

end
```

**routes**

```
 devise_for :users,controllers: { 
    sessions: 'api/v1/sessions',
    registrations: 'api/v1/registrations',
    :passwords => 'api/v1/passwords'

  }
```

Postman

I am hitting this URL with paramaters

```
http://localhost:3000/users/password
Method - Post
Body (raw)

    {
        "email": "some-email@gmail.com"
    }
```

Getting this error **NoMethodError (undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for nil:NilClass):**

Comment: Can you change `:passwords => "api/v1/passwords"` into `passwords:  "api/v1/passwords"`

Comment: It didn't work for me

Comment: thanks it is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The send_reset_password_instructions must be invoked on user instance not a model.

Answer (score 1):

I was calling send_reset_password_instructions on model. It should be invoked on user instance. Here is the code

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  @user.send_reset_password_instructions
  if successfully_sent?(@user)
    head :status => 200
  else
    render :status => 422, :json => { :errors => @user.errors.full_messages }
  end
end
```